# Removing extra occurrences from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `match: (text mentor, text mentee, text area)`. It doesn't have any primary key. I have another table `remain: (text email, int number)`. `email` is the primary key. There are two types of values in `remain.number`: greater than zero and -1. Emails corresponding to `number > 0` refer to mentor and `number = -1` refer to mentee.

What I want is:

1. In first round, for every email in `match.mentor`, if its number of occurrences are greater than the corresponding `remain.number` (`match.mentor = remain.email`), remove those extra entries (tuples).
2. In second round, for every email in `match.mentee`, if it occurs more than once, remove those extra entries (tuples).

How can I do this?

---

Example:

```
remain:

email   number
e1      1
e2      -1
e3      -1
e4      -1
e5      2
e6      2
e7      -1

match:

mentor   mentee  area
e1       e2      x
e1       e3      x
e1       e4      x
e5       e2      x
e6       e7      x
```

Expected result:

```
match:

mentor   mentee  area
e1       e2      x
e6       e7      x
```

First round removes `(e1, e3), (e1, e4)` and second round removes `(e5, e2)`. I have skipped `area` since its irrelevant to the question.

My attempt? I was able to count the number of occurrences of each of the emails, but have no idea how (and if) that can be used to remove extra tuples.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us sample data and expected results as tabular text, along with your current attempt so far.

Comment: @GMB sure give me a minute

Comment: Hi, thank you for adding the additional data, this has helped understand the conditions you are looking to satisfy. How do you handle the ordering of your data? When you say "remove extra entries", what classifies an entry as an extra? Can you rely on the first entry always being the one you want?

Comment: @BarryPiccinni There's no ordering as such in SQL. I'm fine with the solution as long as the 2 conditions are met. I kept `(e1, e2)`, but there can obviously be cases when it is removed and some other tuple is kept. So I don't bother much about the "first" or "last" entries as such

Comment: @AnkitKumar Your sample data implies an ordering. If you changed the order of your sample data, either your expected result would change, i.e order is important, or there are other conditions identifying these rows which you have not made clear. Why would (e1, e4) be removed from your data, but not (e1, e2) for example?

Comment: @BarryPiccinni I just gave an example. If I have a set `{a, b, c}` and I want just one of those (`remain.number` for my question to be precise), all `{a}`, `{b}` and `{c}` satisfy it right? I don't have ordering in my data, apart from row number I guess. No sorting or anything in any way

Comment: @AnkitKumar So whether you get `A`, `B`, or `C` is irrelevant, as long as one (or the number specified in `remain.number`) is returned?

Comment: @BarryPiccinni Yes. You can look at the solution below. It works the way I expected :) . Thanks btw :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select mentor, mentee, area from (
    SELECT *, row_number() OVER (
        ORDER BY mentor, mentee
        ) id, row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY mentor ORDER BY mentor
        ) id1, row_number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY mentee ORDER BY mentee
        ) id2
    FROM MATCH) A, remain
where remain.email = A.mentor and A.id1 <= remain.number and A.id2 <= 1;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, there's a small mistake. You have done `A.id1 <= 1` and `id2 <= 1`. It is true for `mentee`, but not for `mentor`. The maximum number of times you can have `mentor` is given by `remain.number` (and apparently you didn't use `remain` at all)

Comment: Instead of using `A.id1 <= 1`, you can join here with `remain` and use that condition. Great!

Comment: Yeah, sure we can:)

Comment: Your answer still gives incorrect answer. For example, if `remain: (e1, 1)` was `(e1, 2)` ideally I should see 2 tuples in the answer, but your solution gives only 1. Do you mind if I edit your solution to include my solution? (I worked out the correct way, thanks to your solution obviously :))

Comment: Sure go further